# How to build a non trivial Symfony2 website consisting of many controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony, event-handling

I'm planning a symfony2 based website. The default layout will consist of the following blocks:

- Primary header menu
- Secondary side menu
- Sitemap in footer
- Login Form
- Search
- Poll Question
- Shopping Cart

For every part I know how to code my way in Symfony2 by writing a controller and a Twig template. For some parts I'm planing to use bundles such as [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) which provides it's own controllers.

The thing I don't find a good answer for is: *How can I make this all dance together?* My primary-header-menu bundle or FOSUserBundle step up if their routes are triggered and return a response. But that's useless. I need something where all this building blocks process and render their part (almost) regardless of what route was triggered.

This get's particularly interesting with forms. If a form is submitted, it should be handled by the appropriate action. But afterwards all other blocks should render their content before the whole page is returned.

If you know [Drupal](http://drupal.org/): I can implement a form in a block. I'm dealing with this block only and don't have to care about all the other stuff on the page.

If you know [Java/SWING](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html): I can implement an action or a dialog as a self-containing thing. The framework takes care about keeping everything else up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to display different blocks on your pages from different areas of your site, correct?

If that's the case, set the blocks you want to include on your page in your layout.html.twig (or base.html.twig, or whatever you may call it)

Example layout.html.twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Acme Example Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="sidebar-menu-block" class="block">
                {% include 'AcmeBundle:Sidemenu:sideMenu.html.twig' %}
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar-cart-block" class="block">
                {% render url('acme_shopping_cart_block_url') %}
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar-poll-block" class="block">
                {% render url('acme_poll_block_url') %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to include a flat twig template, use 'include'.  If you need a block that requires processing before loading, use 'render'.

Example page(IE: AcmeUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>My Page with a form!</h1>
<form>
   {{ form_widget(form) }}
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

The above example will surround your register.html.twig with all of your blocks defined in layout.html.twig.  Check out the "Including Other Templates" section of the symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#including-other-templates

Comment: "If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to display different blocks on your pages from different areas of your site, correct?" Yes, that's fully correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to search for some time to figure out what "render url" is doing, since it's not a standard twig tag. After all the symfony2 book has the answer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: `{% block body|default('') %}` instead of `{% block body %}{% endblock body %}` is my choice for layout templates :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include complicated blocks that will call other complicated renderings, Twig includes won't be enough. I think you should check out the Dependency Injector, Services and the like. For example, you could create a Twig Service that fetch the last "Poll Question" from your database and display it nicely. Feel free to comment if you're interested in some code.